# In accessing a table declared globally but filled in another method

Tags: c#

I have declared a global variable in a class in c# as

```
 public partial class admin_AnalyseQuery : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    llvsMasterpage m;
    private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
    private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";
    DataTable dt;
```

Here i created a datatable dt as global variable right?

now the datatable dt is filled with the methods as in the screen shots

"BindDatagvAnalyse " - this is a method to bind data to the grid view.

```
 private void BindDatagvAnalyse()
    {
        Guid SchoolID = Guid.Parse(School.SelectedValue);
        Guid YearID = Guid.Parse(Years.SelectedValue);
        Guid VersionID = Guid.Parse(Versions.SelectedValue);
        Guid LessonID = Guid.Parse(Lessons.SelectedValue);
        Guid TeacherID = Guid.Parse(Teachers.SelectedValue);
        Guid LearningunitID = Guid.Parse(Learningunits.SelectedValue);
        Guid DomainID = Guid.Parse(Domain.SelectedValue);
        pnllbl.Visible = true;
        string Schoolname = School.SelectedItem.Text;
        string Yearname = Years.SelectedItem.Text;
        string Versionname = Versions.SelectedItem.Text;
        string Lessonnmae = Lessons.SelectedItem.Text;
        string Teachername = Teachers.SelectedItem.Text;
        string Learningunitname = Learningunits.SelectedItem.Text;
        string Domainname = Domain.SelectedItem.Text;
        lblinfo.Text = Schoolname + "/" + Yearname + "/" + Lessonnmae + "/" + Versionname + "/" + Teachername + "/" + Domainname + "/" + Learningunitname;
        //  Guid PeriodID = Guid.Parse(Periods.SelectedValue);
        dt = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesDomain.GetAllDetailsForgvanalyse(SchoolID, YearID, LessonID, VersionID, TeacherID, LearningunitID, DomainID);
        int count = dt.Rows.Count;
        lblcount.Text = count.ToString();
        int c = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesDomain.GetAllDetailsForgvanalyseCount(SchoolID, YearID, LessonID, VersionID, TeacherID, LearningunitID, DomainID);
        lblstd.Text = c.ToString();
        gvAnalyse.DataSource = dt;
        gvAnalyse.DataBind();
    }
```

I have created this type of 6 methods which will create the table according to dropdowns selection and then call the according method and fill the gvanalyse accordingly which is displayed in screen.

Now i have put a button to create excel sheet from the table.

In the Export Excel button click event i have to create the Excel sheet with the table currently showing in screen.

For that in Button click event i have done this

```
protected void btnexel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] Result;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string school = School.SelectedItem.Text;
            string year = Years.SelectedItem.Text;
            DataTable final = dt;
            // DataTable dt = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesDomain.GetAllDetailsForgvanalyse(SchoolID, YearID, LessonID, VersionID, TeacherID, LearningunitID, DomainID);
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Result = ms.GetBuffer();
            Session["Excel"] = Result;
            Session["dt"] = final;
            Session["school"] = school;
            Session["year"] = year;
            Session["pdf/excel"] = "excel/loondiest/analyse";
            Response.Redirect("~/admin/DownloadPdf.aspx");
        }
}
```

But when i debug it it always shows that table final & dt both are null.

What should i do?

Comment: Can you please add your actual code so we may see what you're trying to do?

Comment: We can't tell why it's happening without seeing what you've written; you should probably post some code.

Comment: ok i am gonna explain with some screen shots..

Comment: @HiralBavisi - we'd probably rather see code as code, rather than screenshots. It's quite common to want to copy & paste code in questions into local projects so that we can debug the code. This would also point to making sure that the code you post compiles and still exhibits the problem you're encountering. But try to remove any code not related to the issue, to keep it small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must persist your `DataTable` in `persistance structure`, because when you post your datas, your datas are lost.

Persistance structure

```
ViewState : on page with post

Session

Cache

Application
```

Sample

```
public DataTable Table
{
  get
  {   
      if(ViewState["KeyTable"] != null)
      {
         return ViewState["KeyTable"] as DataTable;
      }
  }
  set
  {
     ViewState["KeyTable"] = value;
  }
}
```

Use Case :

```
Table = your value;

.....
```

Table =

Comment: I have properly edited my question.Can you please suggest now.

Comment: I'am happy to help you Hiral Bavisi